# database query with start and end date

Tags: date, jpa, between

I do a select and its working perfect but I want to change it to a select with a from and to date, how would I change my sample to do this? I will get the date from a richfaces calender,
I have a filter on my page that selects all the values for the sql select. so I want to a start and end date to that filter and only get the results between those dates. only `"dd/MM/yyyy"` can be used as its not necessary for the time
example of select:

```
myList = database.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Logging t WHERE t.No = :No and t.customer = :customer and t.project = :project and t.task = :tasks").setParameter("No", getNo()).setParameter("customer", getCustomer()).setParameter("project", getProject()).setParameter("task", getTask()).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it for me: `and t.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate` at the end and then just added the setParameter with the values I get from richfaces calender and works perfect!